# Biblioteca estática

Tags: c, lib

Criei uma biblioteca estática em `C`, ou seja, após compilado o arquivo `.c`, gerou um arquivo com extensão `.a`. No arquivo `.c` implementei algumas funções. Como eu poderia ler essa lib em outro programa e chamar uma função dela? Estou apenas dando o include do .h no programa, e quando compilo o programa ele exibe na mensagem de erro: referencia indefinida para func() que segue logo abaixo:

```
#ifndef STATIC_H
#define STATIC_H

extern int func();


#endif
```

Comment: ela esta com extensão .h?

Comment: a biblioteca estática está com extensão .a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1ª Opção e acho que você já deve ter tentado é usar o cabeçalho:

```
#include "libstatic.a"
```

Aponte para o local correto da biblioteca.

2ª Opção encontrada nesta resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705961/how-to-link-to-static-library-in-c):

```
cc -o yourprog yourprog.c -lstatic
```

ou

```
cc -o yourprog yourprog.c libstatic.a
```

3ª Opção também encontrada no SOen:

```
gcc -I. -o jvct jvct.c libjvc.a
```

Encontrei um link que ensina a criar um Lib em C (veja se não esqueceu nenhuma etapa) [Link](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs50/buildlib.html)

Comment: Eu tentei incluir  o .h que contem os prototipos das funções implementadas na biblioteca estática (.a), e compilei o programa usando -l+(nome_lib_static) na hora de compilar, mas na compilção ele da o erro de refencia indefinida na chamada da função da biblioteca.

Comment: Testou a segunda opção, e o link que referenciei?

Comment: Deu certo usando a terceira opção, obrigado!!

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que você já criou um .h exportando as funções da biblioteca; se fez isso basta incluir o .a na linha que monta o seu executável.

Bom, acho melhor colocar um exemplo mais completo:

teste.h:

```
#ifndef STATIC_H
#define STATIC_H

    extern int func();


#endif
```

static.c:

```
#include "teste.h"

int func() {

    return 10;

}
```

app.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "teste.h"

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {

    printf("func() retornou %d\n",func());
    return 0;
}
```

Para compilar:

```
gcc -o static.o -c static.c
ar rcs static.a static.c
gcc -o app.o -c app.c
gcc -o teste app.o static.a
```

Comment: Então, acredito que seja isso. Eu estou usando o extern, mas somento no .h, mesmo assim não deu. Postei o .h na pergunta.